# No internet access after connecting to a second network adapter

Tags: networking, internet, network-adapter, fritzbox

Im connected to the internet via wifi and want to connect to my fritz.box via a wired connection, but it seems that windows always tries to use the wired connection when i'm trying to access the internet via chrome.
I get this error:

> NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I tried setting the IPv4 priority manually (the metric), but it still doesn't work.
When i try accessing any page on internet explorer, i automatically get sent to the fritz.box page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to change a connections order as here described https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/2526067 and set your Internet link order higher.

Although this will be reset every time you'll connect your wired link. If you'll need some automatic solution then use `nvspbind` tool with event-based task in scheduler.

Comment: Damn, i completely forgot this option exists, that was probably it - i already solved my problem by just connecting the fritz.box directly to the internet via wifi and then disabling the wifi on my laptop, but thanks!